# AWS S3 Bucket Policy not working for PUTting files from frontend Javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a bucket on AWS S3. If all is public i can easily upload files with:

```
startUpload = ev => {
    const { file } = this.state
    const { name: filename, type: filetype } = file

    axios.put(`https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/${file.name}`, file, { headers: {
      'Content-Type': filetype
    }})
      .then(res => console.log('success', res))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }
```

I have made the bucket private and set up the bucket policy as such:
(generated from the policy generator)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1564615030380",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1564615027886",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::110286134735:user/andrepadez"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

now my frontend code looks like this:

```
startUpload = async ev => {
    const { file } = this.state
    const { name: filename, type: filetype } = file
    this.setState({ uploading: true })
    const response = await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8080/get-signed-url?filename=${filename}&filetype=${filetype}`)
    const { signedUrl } = response.data
    console.log('uploading')

    axios.put(signedUrl, file, { headers: {
      'Content-Type': filetype
    }})
      .then(res => console.log('success', res) || this.setState({ uploading: false }))
      .catch(err => console.error(err) || this.setState({ uploading: false }))
  }
```

and my backend code:

```
aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
})
const s3 = new aws.S3()
const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.get('/get-signed-url', (req, res) => {
  const { filename, filetype } = req.query

  const params = {
    Bucket: AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: filename,
    // Expires: 60,
    ContentType: filetype
  }

  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, signedUrl) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.send(err)
    } else {
      // const signature = signedUrl.match(/Signature=(\S+)/)[1]

      res.send({ signedUrl })
    }
  })
})
```

I get the following error message when trying to upload:

[image]

Comment: Could you share the response body as well?

Comment: there is no response body... only the error

Comment: So in the network tab if you click on the request and body, it's an empty message?

Comment: +Venkat: yes, "Failed to load Response Data"

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any error in your code. What I see though is that the URL seems to be completely wrong. Structure of signed url follows this pattern:

```
https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/filename?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIHPOEVTLP7M7CKJA&Content-Type=text%2Fhtml&Expires=1564634878&Signature=rD0zsXlVB7Usax9r12Z
```

Look at the bucket name, in your case it is something like

```
clineage-watch-data clineage-watch-data-...PWboty...
```

Bucket name cannot contain space in it as well as it cannot contain upper case letters. Double check the name of your bucket and make sure that `AWS_BUCKET` holds the right value. Also, place console log right before you are sending the signed URL from the backend to verify that the URL is correct and diagnose whether there is an error in bucket name or whether something happens on the frontend when you receive the URL.

Also, try to avoid using permanent credentials in your application if possible, it is agains security best practices.

Comment: the URL is correct, "'https://clineage-watch-data-test.s3.amazonaws.com/Screenshot%202019-07-14%20at%2001.16.11.png?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Content-Type=image%2Fpng&Expires=1564659926&Signature=XXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Depends on how you are running your backend. EC2 - IAM role. Lambda - Lambda execution role. ECS - task role. On prem - IAM user via `aws configure` with permissions to only assume IAM role and then use IAM role credentials. Note that you don't need to specify credentials in your code at all if you are not calling `AssumeRole*` directly. If they are not present, sdk will automatically try to get them via `aws configure`(IAM user) or from instance's metadata(IAM role).